# Apply a req statement to multiple outputs

Tags: r, shiny

Is there any way to apply a `req` command to multiple output objects in a shiny app without having to repeat the `req` statement each time? In the example below, you will see that the `req` statement is repeated in both the `part1` and `part2` outputs.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("commentText", "Input Text"),
  textOutput(outputId = "part1"),
  textOutput(outputId = "part2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$part1 <- renderText({
    req(input$commentText)
    "Hello"
  })
  output$part2 <- renderText({
    req(input$commentText)
    "World!"
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If possible, I would only like to have to input the `req` statement once (the actual use case has 6 different objects tied to the `req` so I'd like to avoid repetition if possible). I tried the following approach using an observer, but this fails when you type in and then delete text (when the text is deleted, 'HelloWorld!' still appears).

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$commentText, {
    req(input$commentText)
    output$part1 <- renderText({
      "Hello"
    })
    output$part2 <- renderText({
      "World!"
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not recommended to nest a render function inside an observer. Instead, you could use a `renderUI` and handle both texts.
2. `req` allows more than one argument. You can check several inputs in one statement.

> req(..., cancelOutput = FALSE) 
> ... Value**s** to check for truthiness.

Attempted solution:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("commentText", "Input Text"),
  textInput("commentText2", "Input More Text"),
  uiOutput(outputId = "part1and2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$part1and2 <- renderUI({
    req(input$commentText, input$commentText2)

    tagList(
      wellPanel("Hello"),
      wellPanel("World!")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```